# Spring boot with spring data repository - cannot autowire own repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a new project with spring boot that will use spring data (spring repositories...), but I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'HQLTester': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.CompanyRepository com.example.HQLTester.companyRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.service.CompanyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.HqlTesterApplication.main(HqlTesterApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.CompanyRepository com.example.HQLTester.companyRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.service.CompanyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.service.CompanyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Here is my project structure

[image]

HqlTesterApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.*")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.service.*")
public class HqlTesterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HqlTesterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

HQLTester.java

```
@Service
public class HQLTester {

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    void testHQL(){
        System.out.println("TEST");
        List<Company> companies = companyRepository.findCompanyWithEmployes2(new Date(), 1l);
        List<Company> companies2 = companyRepository.findCompanyWithEmployes(new Date(), 1l);
    }
}
```

CompanyRepository.java

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    @Query(" SELECT c FROM Company c ,Employee e  LEFT JOIN FETCH c.employees emp WHERE e.id=emp.id and  e.hireDate > :dateee and e.departureDate < :dateee and c.id=:id")
    List<Company> findCompanyWithEmployes2(@Param("dateee") Date dateee, @Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(" SELECT c FROM Employee e  LEFT JOIN FETCH e.company c  WHERE     e.hireDate > :dateee and e.departureDate < :dateee and c.id=:id")
    List<Company> findCompanyWithEmployes(@Param("dateee") Date dateee, @Param("id") Long id);
}
```

Company.java

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Employee> employees;

}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    Date hireDate;

    Date departureDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Company company;

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myServer.com:1521/TESTDB
spring.datasource.username=TESTUSER
spring.datasource.password=TESTUSER
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
```

Could you please tell me what I missed to configure that my repository is not taken in context?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change annotation on HqlTesterApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.service")
@EntityScan("com.model")
public class HqlTesterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HqlTesterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```